# Are the colors of Kal-El's swaddling wraps related to the Jor-El family crest or are they just random colored blankets?

Tags: dc, superman

Do the colors of Supermans baby blankets have any special significance, or they just random colored swaddling wraps?

Comment: Sometimes he's wrapped in yellow, sometimes he's wrapped in brown. I suppose it depends on which version you're seeing. In 1965 he was wrapped in orangey-brown, although this image kind of confuses me: http://media.comicvine.com/uploads/0/40/1672432-super2.jpg

Answer (score 4):

In-universe, Superman's suit is regularly described as having been made from (or at the very least inspired by) the colours of his swaddling clothes found in his escape pod.

I can't find any reference to the colours having any special significance on Krypton but it's fairly clear that (out of universe) the colours were selected because of their connotations with the 'Red, White and Blue' of the American Flag.

[image: Superman's Outfit]
[image: Superman's Outfit 2]

There's an amazingly detailed site [here](http://www.supermanhomepage.com/movies/movies.php?topic=sr-costume-compare) that shows the changes his suit has undergone since Superman Issue #1